# JSON RawMessage Modification

Tags: json, go

Let's say I have below json raw message, I unmarshal as component struct, taking json value out,v.id and v.name. Passed to some dfs function and return me with good things. I then assign them back to id and name.

I realize that within the for loop, it has been updated to good things, however, when I exit for loop, it doesn't update the original JSON raw message. Is there any way to update original JSON message instead of just within the loop?

```
if err := json.Unmarshal(inputs.Components, &component); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }   

for _, v := range component {
        if _, ok := map[v.id+"-"+v.Name]; ok {
            var c string
            var m string
            raw_info1, raw_info2 := dfs(v.id, v.Name, map, &c, &m)
            v.id = raw_info1
            v.name = raw_info2
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is caused by value semantics of `v` in the loop, try assigning `v` back to `component` after mutation, e.g. `component[i] = v`.

Comment: thank you vearutop.. I noticed that the dfs returns *raw_into1 and *raw_info2. New to go language. It is something related to reference type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually marshall back so that it will modify the value inside unmarshall raw json object

Answer (score 0):

I assume component in this case is a map and not a struct, else you cannot iterate like that.
When you range over components, you get the key and value "by value". As such, what you modify is not an element of components, but their copy.
To modify the components you should rewrite you logic like:

```
component[key] = v
```

Comment: Thank you Alok, the comoinent here is a struct not a map...Map is actually a map